# How do i remove my oh my posh installed in vscode?

Tags: oh-my-posh

Please help me, i'm trying to uninstall my oh my posh in vscode terminal
Screenshot is like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKhGe.png

Thank you very much, i much appreaciate it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to vscode but your shell. If you have powershell running as a shell, you'll need to adjust your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new shell profile for VScode Terminal without OMP:

```
New-Item -Path $PROFILE -Type File -Force
```

this will create a new blank profile and overwrite the default one